# how to do tickamount in apex chart using angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

[image: line chart]

How to minminum the labels of xaxis in apex chart using angular ?

```
 intializationChartoption(series: number[]):void {
     this.lineChartOptions = true
   
    this.title ={
      text: 'linechart'
    };

    this.xaxis= {
      
     
      
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        format: 'MM yyyy'
      },
      

     
    };
    

    this.yaxis ={
      show: false,
      showAlways: false
    }
    console.log(this.yaxis)
    this.series = [{
      name: 'java',
      data: series  
    }]
    console.log(this.series)

    this.dataLabels ={
      enabled: false
    }

    this.markers ={
      size: 0
    }
      
    this.chart = {

      
      
      type: "area",
      stacked: false,
      height: 250,
      animations: {
        enabled: false},
      
      
      zoom: {
        type: "x",
        enabled: false,
        autoScaleYaxis: true
      },
      toolbar: {
        show: false
      },
      
    };
  }
```

I have given type date time for x axis but it is not working and in that line chart , values having 8000 data i.e coming from api .

kindly help me to format the data in line chart

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, the `tickAmount` does not apply with type = 'datetime'. In my experience does not play good with type = 'category' either.
The solution I've found is to use type = 'numeric', but then you can override the numbers with your own labels. Like this:

```js
xaxis: ApexXAxis = {
    type: 'numeric',
    tickPlacement: 'between',
    tickAmount: 4,
    decimalsInFloat: 0,
    overwriteCategories: ['0am  ', '7am', '3pm', '11pm'],
  };
```